# std has no member 'getline'?

Tags: c++, io, std, getline

I'm trying to use std::getline, but my compiler is telling me that getline isn't identified?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(){
    using namespace std;
    string line;
    ifstream ifile("test.in");
    if(ifile.is_open()){
        while(ifile.good()){
            getline(ifile,line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is defined in the `string` header.

```
#include <string>
```

Also, your code isn't using anything from `cstring`, `cstdio`, `cmath`, or `cstdlib`; why bother including these?

**EDIT:** To clarify the confusion regarding the `cstring` and `string` headers, `cstring` pulls the contents of the *C runtime library's* `string.h` into the `std` namespace; `string` is part of the *C++ standard library* and contains `getline`, `std::basic_string<>` (and its specializations `std::string` and `std::wstring`), etc. -- two *very* different headers.

Comment: I thought cstring and string were the same, but cstring was for c++?

Comment: @Pig Head: `cstring` is for C-in-C++.  It defines all the old C string functions (`strlen`, etc) in the `std` namespace.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that because a lot of other headers use `cx

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that because a lot of other headers use `cx` instead of `x.h`. This doesn't have a .h, but hey

Comment: Those `cwhatever` standard headers are almost always the same thing: imports of old C headers into the `std` namespace.  It doesn't have much to do with C++, except inasmuch as it adds C compatibility with less namespace pollution.

Comment: @Pig Head - There are three different headers being discussed: `<string>`, `<string.h>`, and `<cstring>`. `<cstring>` and `<string.h>` *are* more-or-less the same. `<string>` and `<string.h>` are vastly different, so `<cstring>` and `<string>` are also vastly differently.

Answer (score 3):

As ildjarn points out, the function is declared in `<string>`, and I'm suprised you didn't get an error at:

```
string line;
```

Also, this:

```
 while(ifile.good()){
      getline(ifile,line);
 }
```

is not the way to write  a read loop. You MUST test the success of the read operation, not the current stream state. You want:

```
while( getline(ifile,line) ) {
}
```

Comment: This is old, I know, but I thought I'd just chime in and state that the method above for the read loop breaks the programming cardinal rule of "Assignment in condition" which will throw an error if using strict standards.

while ((getline(ifile, line) !== false) {
.
.
.
}

would be better

Comment: I did #include <string.h> and I could declare strings, but getline was not recognized. I changed to #Include <string> to get getline working also.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because getline comes from the string library, you need to `#include <string>` or `#include <cstring>`